# get_post_meta return mistake value in plugin

Tags: wordpress

I want to use get_post_meta in plugin but it is returning wrong value
following is my code:

```
    $wp_tags = array("{ID}","{title}","{music128}","{excerpt}","{content}","{author}","{short_url}","{full_url}","{tags}","{categories}");
    $wp_subs = array(
    $post->ID,
    $post->post_title,
    $post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'music128',true),
    wp_trim_words($post->post_content, $excerpt_length, "..."),
    $post->post_content,
    get_the_author_meta("display_name",$post->post_author),
    wp_get_shortlink($ID),
    get_permalink($ID),
    $tags,
    $categories
    );
```

get_post_meta result is http://*******.com/Music/shahrivar97/Ebrahim20%20-20Deylar.mp3 this link error 404 not found
 but orginal url is http://*******.com/Music/shahrivar97/Ebrahim%20Alizade%20%20-%20Sani%20Deylar.mp3

Comment: Are you sure? This line:
$post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'music128',true),
will produce boolean value and will insert it into your array.
This is first problem. Second, can you show us your code to insert your link into post_meta? And please use http://example.com/ instead of http:://*******.com/, it's easier to read.

Comment: yes i am sure. my code in post is  <?php $post_meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'music128',true); if (!empty($post_meta)) { ?>
    <li><a  title="MP3 128 kbps" href="<?php echo $post_meta; ?>"> MP3 128 kbps</a></li>

Comment: And this code works? Shows you valid url? And again, please provide code for inserting those values into post meta. Something with similar to `update_post_meta` instead of `get_post_meta`

Comment: yes that work in post but dosnt work in plugin. valid url: http://dl.rosemusics.com/Music/shahrivar97/Ebrahim%20Alizade%20%20-%20Sani%20Deylar.mp3   and 404 url is http://dl.rosemusics.com/Music/shahrivar97/Ebrahim20%20-20Deylar.mp3

Comment: First of all, I was wrong at the very beginning, I don't know why, I saw "==" instead of "=" in the array. So, this part is ok.
I see problems with url_encoding. The url you are provided as valid, is set and get without any problem with wordpress meta.
We need to see more, to see the problem.

Comment: i confused that work in my post but in plugin return 404 url!

Comment: THIS IS ECHO CODE:  <option title='<?php echo __("The post meta of this post", "twp-plugin"); ?>'>{music128}</option>